# how to add documentation to undocumented production library

Tags: c#

I use a production library (namely itextsharp) in my project, this library doesn't ship with intellisense documentation.

I'd like to build (partial) documentation project.

Is this possible without access to the source code?

Comment: The ITextSharp nuget package comes with XML documentation.

Comment: You mean adding text information when the intellisense context popup shows up? Like method descriptions, parameters explanations and the like

Comment: @Amy yes you're right, but visual studio doesn't show it in intellisense, do you know why? anyway this is beyond the scope of this question because i have other libraries with absolutely no documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I think that intellisense data for external libraries are defined in a xml file which should ship alongside the said library. It should also have the same named but an xml extension instead of dll.

There are a bunch of xml tags that Intellisense will expect which are [documented on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ast78ax.aspx). Also some open source libraries come with such documentation, like Unity for instance, which will give you a "working" example of such a xml file. You can find an [example here on github](https://github.com/drostar/UnityIntelliSenseDocumentation)